# Segmentation fault (core dumped) in c (sending text to array)

Tags: c, arrays, coredump

I'm writing code which takes input from the command line (a redirected text file) and sends the data to an array in c. However whenever I run it I get a segmentation fault (core dumped) error. Here is my code:

```
  int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    char *experiments[20];
    int data[10][20];

int b=0;
char *name = NULL;
name=malloc(100);
sendToArray(data, experiments);
while(b==0){
    int input=0;
    printf("\n");
    printf("Data set analysis\n");
    printf("1. Show all the data\n");
    printf("2. Calculate the average for an experiment\n");
    printf("3. Calculate the average across all experiments\n");
    printf("4. QUIT\n");
    printf("Selection: ");
    scanf("%d", &input);

    switch (input) {
        case 1:
            if(argc!=0){
                displayAll(data, experiments);
            }
            else{
                printf("Oops, something went wrong!\n");
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            if(argc!=0){
                printf("\n");
                printf("Enter the name of the experiment: ");
                scanf("%[^\n]", name);
                individualAverage(name, experiments, data);
            }
            else{
                printf("Oops, something went wrong!\n");
            }
            break;
        case 3:
            if(argc!=0){
                allAverage(experiments, data);
            }
            else{
                printf("Oops, something went wrong!\n");
            }
            break;
        case 4:b=1;;
            break;

        default:
            printf("Oops, something went wrong!\n");
            break;
    }
}
return 0;
```

}

Thats the beginning of main, which calls this function:

```
void sendToArray(int data[10][20], char *experiments[20]){
char line[100];
char line2[100];


char *temp1;
int temp;
int i=0, c=0;
while(!strcmp(line, "*** END ***")){
    scanf("%[^\n]", line);
    scanf("%*c");
    scanf("%[^\n]", line2);
    scanf("%*c");
    for(i=0; i<10; i++){

        temp1 = strtok(line2, " ");
        temp = atoi(temp1);
        data[c][i] = temp;
    }
    experiments[c] = line;
    c++;

}
numExperiments = c+1;


}
```

I changed the function to allocate 100 bits of memory to each line, however I still get the core dump. Also, if I do redirect a text file, the program loops through main infinitely.
Thanks if anyone can help me find my mistake!

Here is my sample input file!, which is called in bash by ./dataset < textfile :

```
Experiment One
3 10 8 7 3 2 9 7 5 6
Experiment Two
10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100
Control Group
5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
*** END ***
```

Okay, thank you to everyone, I fixed the memory dump, however, whenever I pipe the text file the program still loops infinitely.

Comment: If you provided an example input file, people might be able to suggest a good way to solve your problem, rather than just correcting a handful of errors.

Comment: Now you need to correct the other mistakes pointed out in my answer.

Comment: `while(!strcmp(line, "*** END ***")) {` will probably never run the loop... it terminates when a line *isn't* "*** END ***".

Comment: @dmitri Are you sure? Does the ! not change that?

Comment: @davir Thank you for your help! Now on to fix the rest :P

Comment: if the line *is* "*** END ***" `strcmp()` returns 0, which is negated to 1 and the loop runs.

Comment: ...there are a lot of other issues, though.

Comment: I don't think this question has anything to do with bash.

Comment: Just to satisfy my curiosity, *why* do you want to do this in *C*? For what this application superficially appears to be, there are much easier languages. Is it an exercise of some kind? A homework problem?

Comment: @Emmet it is indeed homework :P

Comment: I am much more fluent in languages such as c++ and java!

Comment: @Norton: When you're writing an answer it helps to know. I think there's a “homework” tag, actually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you never allocate memory for line and line2.
You could declare them as proper arrays, e.g.:

```
char line[32];
char line2[32];
```

This is what is causing the segmentation fault, but fixing that you would have another error: you are passing local addresses to the experiments array. You can fix that either by allocating the line arrays via malloc, or by allocating proper memory for experiments and then copying each string in line with strcpy or something.
Also, I am pretty sure that

```
scanf("%[^\n]\n", line);
```

is invalid. What you want is

```
scanf("%[^\n]", line);
scanf("%*c");
```

Comment: or using `strdup` on the local buffers

Answer (score 0):

You reference `data[c][i]` without checking that `c<20`. That's highly unsafe and can result in an illegal memory access (a segfault).

Try restricting `c` to be lower than 20. Do you still get the error?

Comment: Made sure to add that!